# extracting value from python double dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict = {}
with open(path, 'rt', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    pairs = f.readlines()
    for pair in pairs:
        key = pair.split(',')[0]
        value1 = pair.split(',')[1]
        value2 = pair.split(',')[2]
        value3 = pair.split(',')[3]
        dict[key] = {'a': value1}
        dict[key] = {'b': value2}
        dict[key] = {'c': value3}
    print(dict)
```

The code above is a simplified version, but the structure is the same.
when I run print, it shows only the last inside dictionary.
I mean, only {key : {'c':value3}}.
I don't understand why this functions this way without the two inside dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You're reassigning a new 1-pair dict to the key three times.

You're looking for something like

```
dict = {}
with open(path, "rt", encoding="UTF8") as f:
    pairs = f.readlines()
    for pair in pairs:
        key, value1, value2, value3, *rest = pair.split(",")
        dict[key] = {"a": value1, "b": value2, "c": value3}
    print(dict)
```

Comment: I think it's not a good practice to use `dict` as a variable. You may know that `dict` is a built-in function in Python.

Comment: Yes, but in general (in function scope anyway) it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Each dictionary key is unique and you assign values to the same key so only the last value is assign.
You can avoid that by

```
dict[key] = {'a': value1}
dict[key].update({'b': value2})
dict[key].update({'c': value3})
```

This way the `print(dict)` will print

```
 {key : {'a':value1, 'b':value2 'c':value3}}
```